# Google Sheets' IMPORTXML pulling from the wrong region

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I'm using `IMPORTXML` to get the price of an electronics component from Mouser:
[image: Screenshot]
If the prices are refreshed as a result of me editing the spreadsheet, it requests from my computer, and results in the price being listed as USD and the datasheet as listed from the US. However, if the cells are updated automatically due to Google's once per hour thing, the prices are listed in euros.

The euro prices are not equivalent to the USD prices, which is why I am not going to do a currency conversion. For example, the breadboards are $8.80, but are listed as 8,85 € which converts to almost $10 (over than a dollar more expensive).

How can I tell Google to either

1. Make the IMPORTXML request with a cookie that stores locale data?
2. Make the IMPORTXML request from the US?

My locale and timezone in the spreadsheet are set to the US:
[image: Screenshot]

[Here's a link to the spreadsheet itself.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Fb1I5YvNIawkWM-ukAnNsta1N80Cecj5ng4if-WDqk/edit?usp=sharing)